# Open URL on new tab (on parent) from popup opened from iframe on parent

Tags: javascript, html

A popup is fired from an iframe. Inside this popup im trying to link the user to new page, this page should open on new tab on the parent, but for the popup the parent in this case is the iframe and not the container of the iframe (the parent of the iframe) where im actually want to open a new tab.

Is this possible? If not, how can I open the link on a new browser windows?

So far I tried this but is not working:

```
<button onclick="parent.window.open=('http://mysite.com/app_dev.php/gifts','_blank')" class="btn btn-primary">Altri Regali »</button>
```

Comment: Quick and blunt idea: have you tried `parent.parent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://mysite.com/app_dev.php/gifts','_blank')" class="btn btn-primary">Altri Regali »</button>
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8RdLx/)